# Flutter Firebase: How do I only record the first name of a display name in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, displayname-attribute

I have the following code writing to Firestore for an auth class with Google Sign in:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class AuthService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;


  Future<FirebaseUser> get getUser => _auth.currentUser();

  Stream<FirebaseUser> get user => _auth.onAuthStateChanged;

  Future<FirebaseUser> googleSignIn() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      updateUserData(user);

    Future<void> updateUserData(FirebaseUser user) {
    DocumentReference usersRef = _db.collection('users').document(user.uid);

    return usersRef.setData({
      'uid': user.uid,
      'email': user.email,
      'displayName': user.displayName,
      'photoUrl': user.photoUrl,
      'lastActivity': DateTime.now(),
    }, merge: true);

  }

  Future<void> signOut() {
    return _auth.signOut();
  }

}
```

I need to only collect the first name to Firestore. Is there a logical way that I can do it within my auth process? Thanks!

Comment: So you only want to save user first name in firestore?

Comment: yes that is correct. Basically what we are building is surrounded by privacy and we dont want to call upon a users full name in a stream. This is why recording just the first name would be the best option for each user.

Comment: return usersRef.setData({
      'displayName': user.displayName,
    }, merge: true);

Comment: Use this code in your project

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. I still need 'uid', 'email', 'photo url' and 'last activity' ```   return usersRef.setData({
      'uid': user.uid,
      'email': user.email,
      'displayName': user.displayName, (Just record the first name instead of the full name)
      'photoUrl': user.photoUrl,
      'lastActivity': DateTime.now(),
    }, merge: true);

  }```

Comment: displayName.split("")[0] will give you the first name

Comment: 'displayName': user.displayName.split("")[0], This gave me the first letter in Firestore but not the full first name.

Comment: displayName.split(" ")[0] sorry use this

Comment: If it helped you upvote it

Comment: You have to answer it, not comment for me to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string `spilt()` function as follows:

```
  Future<void> updateUserData(FirebaseUser user) {
    DocumentReference usersRef = _db.collection('users').document(user.uid);
    List<String> spiltName =value.user!.displayName!.split(" ");
    return usersRef.setData({
      'uid': user.uid,
      'email': user.email,
      'displayName': spilName.first, 
      'photoUrl': user.photoUrl,
      'lastActivity': DateTime.now(),
    }, merge: true);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to identify the first name of the user's displayName from GoogleSignIn. User first names could possibly consist of two or three names. If you're considering the **first** name from the displayName to be its 'first name', then you can split on the displayName and fetch its first index.

```dart
user.displayName.split(' ')[0];
```

Note that it's possible for `displayName` to return null. What you can do here is prompt the user to update their displayName and pass the String to `user.updateDisplayName(displayName)`